# Prove "Any open subset of $\Bbb R$ is an at most countable union of pairwise disjoint open intervals”.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $E$ be a nonempty open subset of $\Bbb R$. There is a collection $A$ of subsets of $\Bbb R$ satisfying the following:
>
> - $(i)$ Each element of $A$ is an open interval (possibly infinite) and any two distinct members of $A$ are disjoint;
> - $(ii)$ $A$ is at most countable;
> - $(iii)$ $E =\bigcup\limits_{G\in A}G$.
>
> > Prove that ”Any open subset of $\Bbb R$ is an at most countable union of pairwise disjoint open intervals”.

I don't know any structure theorems. I only have done a course on real analysis. Which dealt with compact sets and all.

Comment: **Hint :** Make a partition of $E$ in its connected components. Prove that each of these components is an open interval. And to prove that they are in countable number, define an injection from the set of the connected components into $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Prove any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of open intervals whose the finite endpoints are rational. The collection of such intervals is countable. Eventually, if two of these intervals are not disjoint in the decomposition of $E$, you can merge them.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe can u be more explicit

Comment: @raman Do you know what a connected component is ?

Comment: no. i know a set is connected iff it is an interval

Comment: Ok, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components

Comment: can u do without that

Comment: @Halbaroth can u explain please

Answer (score -1):

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the set of the intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ with rational endpoints and $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ an open set.

1. For all $x \in E$, prove there exist a rational $r_x > 0$ and a rational $q_x$ such that $x \in\, ]r_x-q_x, q_x + r_x[$ and $]r_x-q_x, q_x + r_x[ \subset E$. **Hint:** use the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Deduce that $E$ can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal{I}$.
3. Prove that $\mathcal{I}$ is countable. **Hint:** use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable.
4. Deduce you can write $E$ as a countable union of elements of $\mathcal{I}$.
5. Let $E = \cup_{\alpha \in A} I_{\alpha}$ be such a union. For each $\alpha \in A$, prove there exists a largest open interval $J_{\alpha}$ such that $I_{\alpha} \subset J_{\alpha} \subset E$. This $J_{\alpha}$ is not necessary in $\mathcal{I}$.
6. Conclude you can write $E$ as a countable union of **pairwise disjoint** intervals.